# What kind of clause it is?

Tags: grammar

"All you have to do is maintain the rules properly"

Here,What kind of clause is "All you have to do"?

Comment: Looks like a *subject* clause attaching to copula / verb ***is,*** to me (syntactically it's also a *noun,* same as, say ***The trick** is to stick to the rules*).

Comment: It's not a clause; it's an NP consisting of a fused-head determiner (*All*) modified by a relative clause with a null relativizer (*[that] you have to do*).

Answer (score 1):

"*All you have to do*" is not a clause there. The subject of the sentence is "*all*" which is a noun there.

Its long version is:

> All **that** you have to do

"*That you have to do*" is an adjective relative clause defining the noun "*all*".

But of course, you can omit "*that*".

Examples;

> **All I want you to do** is to love me.
>
> **All you are saying** is "*It's not my mistake!*", and you are doing nothing else!